# I set the Google Authorized Redirect URI to a URI on my live/test server, but Google reports a redirect URI of localhost

Tags: java, oauth, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google calendar. I've created 3 projects: dev, test and live, and have set the redirect URIs to https://liveURL, https://testURL, and http://localhost.

Adding an event using the Google Calendar API works in localhost, but I get a redirect URI mismatch error - Google uses http://localhost:43832/Callback appending the code and scope to the URI (the port number changes every time).

I know I'm setting the redirect URI, as this is parts of the clientsSecrets I pass (in Test):

"redirect_uris" : [ "https://golioio.herokuapp.com/tasks/addToGoogleCalendar", "https://golioio.herokuapp.com/tasks/addToGoogleCalendar/", "https://golioio.herokuapp.com", "https://golioio.herokuapp.com/","https://golioio.herokuapp.com/Callback" ]

I included the app root as well.

I've spent 7 days reading the docs, SO answers and debugging and, to be honest, I've had enough.  Any ideas anyone?

Comment: are you getting that **uri_redirect_mismatch** in your browser?

Comment: Yes.  I've quit using Google Calendar and instead am using AddEvent.com to allow users to add events to the calendar of their choice (iCal, Outlook, Google).